# Facebook access tokens expiring for unknown reason

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**EDIT from @avs099:** I'm starting the bounty on this post as I have exactly the same issue. I summarize the problem here, and leave the post itself without any changes at the bottom for the reference.

---

**What we have:** Facebook page access token, obtained as described here: [Authenticating as a Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) and which live was extended to 60 days with new [fb_exchange_token](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) request.

**What is the problem:** this token works for some time - sometimes I can post hundreds of photos to my fan page in the period of several days; sometimes it's literally few photos - and then I start getting either

> (OAuthException) Error invalidating access token: The session has been
>   invalidated because the user has changed the password.

or

> (OAuthException) Error invalidating access token: Session does not
>   match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the
>   password since the time the session was created or Facebook has
>   changed the session for security reasons.

exceptions from the Facebook - but of course I did not do change password or deauthorized the app.

**Additional information:** Not sure if that matters but:

1. Sometimes I start using token few days after I request it from the Facebook
2. Token is requested (by the C# backend) from the server
   which is located in a different geographical region from the desktop
   app which posts photos to the fan page.
3. It happens *sometime* that several different desktop apps post photos from different PCs (i.e. different IPs I guess)

Anybody has a clue what's going on and how to resolve this?

Thank you.

---

I have a facebook app that serves two purposes:

1) Allows users to facebook connect with my site
 2) Allows my site to post to my sites facebook fan page wall

What I'm concerned about is the 2nd usage. I used to be able to set the permissions for an app on a fan page to just allow posting (via the php sdk) without any concern about an access token. Now I've created some new fan pages and that functionality seems to have been removed. Alright, so I go through the whole process of getting an access token (successfully) for the user (always me or another admin of my facebook fan pages) and use that token to get the access tokens for the fan pages I manage (I have the manage_pages permission and so do the other admins for the pages I want to post to). However by the engine gets around to posting content to my fan pages the tokens have expired with one of two error messages:

Error invalidating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.

or

OAuthException: Error invalidating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.

But this isn't an access token dependent on outside users, only internal people (me and one other guy right now). We aren't changing our passwords or doing anything. I've even tested it by logging out of facebook after acquiring tokens and it works fine. It's just after a little while they expire for no reason that I can determine. When I get the tokens I can check them on the debugging tool and they are supposed to last 60 days (according to the doc) although the tool says they never expire.

I've set up the system so when it fails to post to the page I get an email with the link to my site to update the tokens.

Anyone have a clue what's going on?

Comment: Have any of the users been in a security lockout from Facebook? this cycles the tokens in the same way a password change does

Comment: hmm... what exactly is "security lockout"? If I enter my password incorrectly - will that be the case? I do not recall any unusual activity - so most likely the answer is "no". If I give you expired token - will you be able to trace its history and figure out the reason why it was cancelled?

Comment: I was never able to completely solve this issue but it seems to have at least subsided. I set up my server to email me if the tokens expire with a link to a page that generates new tokens and saves them in the db. The tokens haven't mysteriously expired in a at least a week now though.

Comment: @Igy - sorry for bothering you but is there a way for you to look at access token and trace its history and let me know why it has expired? Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem in one of my applications, and couldn't find a way to solve it at first. The biggest problem was the Facebook error message that many times didn't explain the actual cause. For example I got the "OAuthException: Error invalidating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password" error when the actual fault was that the token had expired.
My solution to this was to first check the token by trying a graphQuery 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=token...'. If this failed I extended the token with fb_exchange_token query.

Answer (score 2):

As Mikhail pointed out, if you get an error reporting that the token is invalid cause user has changed the password. Odds are you are requesting a new token somewhere hidden in the code, when you already have a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly related to this bug? https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/241373692605971?browse=search_4fb4832bcaf7b1549293950

Comment: thanks for the link, but i do not think so... i'm sure tokens are valid for more than 2 hours. The problem is why do they suddenly expire - what's causing this..

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my app - sometimes tokens expiring.

One of the find reason: sometimes my app ask for new token while old token is valid and FB return an error or i couldn't save new token for some reason. 
After that old token expire - only one token for pair user-app may be valid.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution is to ask the user to delete the application from it's profile, and allow it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and resolved it "reinstalling the app to users facebook applications". it may help you if nothing answers to problem.

To do that:

1. facebook user who is facing the problem goes to its facebook page
2. he/she removes your app from his/her application list.
3. Retry to login via facebook sdk on android.

Answer (score -1):

You can fetch the unauthorized token so a new token is requested (or whatever you like).

I can provide a nice explanation but you can read it all here:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Comment: the question was "why token expires", not "how to handle that"