# Detecting Facebook OAuth token expiration

Tags: facebook, oauth

I have a Facebook application that does scheduled posts on fan pages.

To do this, the app acquires an OAuth token to use for posting on the page. To get this token, the user needs to visit the app. However sometimes Facebook invalidates these tokens, at least if the user changes their FB password and it seems in some other security-related cases too.

When this happens, the app will fail to post the scheduled post and users are unhappy. How should I resolve this? I could email the users when their token expires, but how would I detect the expiration? Given I have 100,000+ users, it would be expensive to poll the tokens very often.

Comment: I tried to do the exact same thing, but the token for me doesn't even last more than a few hours. How long does the token last with you?

Comment: same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486975/facebook-access-tokens-expiring-for-unknown-reason - would love to get solution for this...

Comment: regarding "how to detect the expiration" - you will get OAuthException when posting to Fan page: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/ - or do you want to detect that in advance? then do nightly "/<<user_id>>/?accessToken=<<Token from DB>>" checks. Nothing else as far as I know.

Comment: @BeemerGuy.net you need to exchange the code GET arg to get the actual 2 month token using https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well do directly answer your question, here you go: [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Enter the Access_token there to check its validity and other info. But I know that wouldn't solve your problem in general. I can help you in the right direction.

---

You see token validity is affected by the permissions you asked from the user. There is this `offline_access` permission that gives you an access token that won't time-out, not the regular hour-long tokens. And I'm sure you know this since you're already able to schedule user posts.

Unfortunately, `offline_access` is now [deprecated by Facebook (see this link)](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/). From now on, Facebook will give us 2-month access_token by default, even without the permission. From then on, we'll need to "refresh" or extend the access token. Read more on that link.

And about your problem in use changing password, logs out, etc, Well Facebook has its own [dedicated blog post about it as well, see here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/).

---

If you wanna take the path of checking token validity yourself, you can setup a CRON that runs every hour or everyday (depends on you), and do a quick API call for each token (/me). If it fails or generated an error, token expired.

Much better if you'll do it every minute: 10 to 20 tokens to check, so it wont have a heavy burden on your server doing 100,000+ calls in one execution.

Comment: "refreshing" won't help if token was cancelled by Facebook.

Comment: yes, expired tokens can't be refreshed. even if the cause is timeout, not password-change. if you also don't want to setup a CRON to check everytime, you can just send an email when the scheduled post actually fails. Ask them to login again and post it immediately.

Comment: Thanks dragonjet. By checking token validity, of course I meant through software. But doing millions of API calls is still expensive. I'm sending the emails too but currently I'm doing it after I already failed to use the token (because it would be too expensive to poll constantly for token validity), so from customer point of view my app randomly doesn't work and I get a lot of complaints.